# Returning invoicable time to 'outstanding time' pool

Tags: quickbooks

I use Quickbooks Professional 2009.

When I create a customer invoice for a period with ‘outstanding time’ Quickbooks asks me to include it by checking off boxes; fine that works.  But if I need to re-do that invoice and delete the first one Quickbooks does not return the time on that invoice to the ‘outstanding time’ pool.  How do I denote that time on a deleted invoice is once again ‘outstanding’ and must be flowed back into a new invoice for a period?

Answer (score 1):

If you select the 'Items' tab on an invoice (or a bill), then the bottom right (QB2009) has a 'Time' button.  Press this and you are prompted for the period from which time for the vendor is pulled and inserted into the 'Items' tab.

If your time has entries corresponding to Items in the (Service) Items list then your time will populate the bill appropriately.

Populating an Invoice to a customer works similarly.